# Visual Studio PowerShell Load listBox with files

Tags: winforms, powershell, visual-studio-2019

I am looking for a way to populate a list box object with a dynamic list. Basically I want to write a Foreach loop that will go into a folder and pull out files and clean the names up and then list them for execution. i have a For Each Loop Below but it needs the `.FullName` to be able to execute. i would prefer to use `.Name`

```
$button18_Click = {


if($comboBox1.SelectedIndex -and $combobox2.SelectedIndex -eq -1 ){ 

 $textbox5.BackColor = 'Red'
    $textbox4.BackColor = 'Red'
    $textbox4.Text= "Please Choose Driver"
    $textBox5.Text="Please Choose Van"

 }


Else{

$listbox1.Items.Clear()
$FileItem = GCI $textBox1.Text -Filter *.pdf
Foreach($File in $FileItem){
$ListBox1.Items.Add($File.Name)


  $textbox4.Text= "Driver Selected"
   $textBox5.Text="Van Selected"
  $textbox4.BackColor = 'Info'
  $textbox5.BackColor = 'Info'
  $textBox12.Text = $comboBox1.SelectedItem + " - " + $comboBox2.SelectedItem + " - " + $dateTimePicker1.Text 


}
}
}
```

[image]

Once `Items` are in the `listbox1` i then have this code below to move the selected `Items` into `listbox2`

```
  $listbox1_DoubleClick={


    if ($listbox1.SelectedIndex -gt -1)
    {

       $listBox2.Items.Add($listBox1.SelectedItem);
       Move-Item $listbox2.Items $textbox2.text
       Get-ChildItem $textBox2.Text -Filter *.pdf | rename-item -NewName {((get-date).ToString("HH.mm.ss.")+,$_.name)}
       $listBox1.Items.Remove($listBox1.SelectedItem);
       $MJI3 = GCI $textBox2.Text -Filter *.pdf
       Move-Item $MJI3.FullName $textBox3.Text

    }   
}
```

like is said if i have the `.FullName` this all works perfectly fine, but the appearance looks to messy. especially when my GUI is busy enough.

[image]

Comment: Why not add the whole `FileInfo` object: `$ListBox2.Items.Add($File12)`, and then reference `$ListBox2.Items.FullName` inside the second action block?

Comment: i have updated my question sorry i posted the wrong button command

Comment: Same difference :) `$ListBox1.Items.Add($File)`

Comment: Ok that does make sense thank you, I will try that tomorrow and keep you posted

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i thought i understood what you mean but it turns out i don't any chance you could write what i need to do please